# ScriptDb operational limits

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that generates about 20,000 small objects with about 8 simple properties. My desire was to toss these objects into ScriptDb for later processing of the data.

What I'm experiencing though is that even with a savebatch operation that the process takes much longer then desired and then silently stops. By too much time, it's often greater then the 5 min execution limit, though without throwing any error. The script runs so long that I've not attempted to check a mutation result to see what didn't make it, but from a check after exectution it appears that most do not.

So though I'm quite certain that my collection of objects is below the storage size limit, is there a lesser known limit or throttle on accesses that is causing me problems? Are the number of objects the culprit here, should I be instead attempting to save one big object that's a collection of the lessers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the amount of data you're writing.  I know you can store 20,000 small objects, you just can't write that much in 5 minutes.  Write 1000 then quit.  Write the next thousand, etc.  Run your function 20 times and the data is loaded.  If you need to do this more/automated, use [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptapp#newTrigger).

Comment: I can understand how that could be, and guess it shows my ignorance of how backends work, but it begs the question why is it taking so long to do this via ScriptDb, since if I take the objects, jsonstringify them, then dump the string to the google drive it's a matter of seconds?